# Using Firebase analytics for Unity on iOS prevents the use of promotional IAP

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, firebase-analytics

We are now preparing our game for the new iOS 11 promotional IAP, and it seems that when Firebase Analytics is enabled, we do not get the second call to the IAP event.

Scenario:
- Firebase analytics are enabled
- We open the app on iOS (ver 11) with the promotional iAP link
- We see the IAP window
- We get back to the iOS main screen (press the home button)
- We press the iAP link again
- We get into the app, and do not see the iAP window

The same scenario with firebase analytics disabled is working for us.

It took us a lot of time to understand that this caused the error.

We think that somehow, using firebase analytics blocks the iAP event from getting into other modules, does anyone else encountered this behavior?

Comment: When did you register for the IAP observer? It should be as early as possible.

Comment: @adbitx, of course, we do it first thing on game initialize. And we do see the IAP window on the first time, but not on the second time (what the game is already open in the background).

Comment: When you say the window, do you mean that your IAP observer is called again or is that the iOS alert message? Thanks